# Windows EC7 Thin Client Shell invisible application

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce

I've been playing with a wince 7 device and i'm trying to have it run in kiosk mode (get rid of the windows 95/98 shell and replace it with an app I wrote). The problem is since I replace the default shell with the Thin Client one, the application is invisible/inaccessible (the only thing i see is the default win ec7 wallpaper). I've tried msdn and googling for a solution but i haven't found anything.
I'm guessing i have some dependencies missing but i have no idea what.
I know the application is working because it sends a message via rs232 every 5 sec.
Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, for WinCE5 at least, if you replace the shell (shell..exe) then you must provide the minimal API that the shell code does. The shell may manage windows and if you just replace that, there is no window. It may also be that some API is not yet loaded when your app starts. There are API functions to check if an API set is loaded. I recommend to not replace the shell but instead write a full screen kiosk mode app.

Comment: Hi josef, thanks for the comment. I assumed the Thin client shell would simply work since it came with wince and every article i've seen so far don't mention anything i have't done. As for start priority, I've made my application dependent on everything else so I don't think it could start before any API

Comment: Is the thin client shell not for accessing remote apps only? What programming language did you use for your app?

Comment: I wasn't aware the thin client shell was for remote apps only. Every kiosk type application tutorial uses a modified version of the thin client shell and I was under the impression it is basically the same as the WinCe2013 shell... The programming language i've used is C# and I included it into the OS using CEComponentWiz